# How many blue balls must you choose to guarantee that you have at least $3$ light blue balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bag contains $4$ light blue balls, $5$ dark blue balls,  and $10$ sea blue balls.  How many blue balls must you choose to guarantee that you have at least $3$ light blue balls?

My first reaction was ${19} \choose {3}$, but that would mean we are selecting more balls than there are in the bag.

Answer (score 2):

$5 + 10 + 3 = 18$ balls, by the Pigeonhole Principle! You can choose $5$ dark blue balls, $10$ sea blue balls, then the remaining 3 balls you choose must be light blue.

Comment: I agree with 18 but not with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about binomial coefficients, for example $\binom{19}{3}$ you are talking about the number of ways to chose 3 elements out of 19.

These sort of problems normally require you to think what is the worst possible case, in this case the worst thing that can happen is that you have drawn 2 light blue balls and all of the other balls before having drawn a third blue ball. This can happen in 5+10+2=17 draws. So its possible to draw 17 balls and still not have 3 light blue balls.

Now: what happens if you draw 18 balls? assume that you have drawn 18 balls but you have less than 3 blue balls. Then that means you have at least 16 non-light blue balls. But there are only 15 non-light blue balls, clearly this can't happen.